# chocolatey pauses during download or install, until button is pressed

Tags: package-management, chocolatey

Issue: When installing a list of programs using Chocolatey, it will sometimes pause during the download or install and won't continue until I return to the CMD window and tap a button.

For example, I was just installing Audacity, left it to finish on its own, went away for 15+ minutes, and when I came back it hadn't finished the download. I tapped enter and it immediately said the download finished and started the install.

My background: This is my first day using Chocolatey. I have some experience using apt-get on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short it is a bug somewhere. It's rarely seen, so it's hard to know exactly what causes it. Chocolatey does have an execution timeout, so it will eventually fail the package. You can even [control that timeout](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsReference#default-options-and-switches).

If you are able to get it to repeatedly do this, please follow up with an issue at https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/new and provide the detailed output from `choco install pkgname --debug --verbose`. We'd like to determine what causes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might be actually an issue with the Windows Command Prompt itself and not with Chocolatey. I noticed similar behaviour with other scripts as well and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883530/why-is-my-command-prompt-freezing-on-windows-10). It seems to be related to the QuickEdit mode or in particular switching into "selection" mode unintentionally, which will pause execution.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm sure this is it, but I don't run Windows anymore so can't confirm.